# How to do short return

Tags: javascript

In javascript how can I do short return, like

```
isBad(x) || return false;
```

equals to

```
if(isBad(x)) { return false; }
```

Comment: `return false` isn't an expression. You can't.

Comment: Does `isBad(x)` return a bool? Then simply `return isBad(x);`

Comment: Depends on what the rest of the function does.

Comment: OP, is there something still unclear ?

Comment: @Pimmol, What if requirement is not  to return if `isBad(x)` is `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `||` and `&&` [binary logical operators need expressions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-binary-logical-operators).

[`return` doesn't make an expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-return-statement).

So you can't write this kind of obfuscated shortcut statement. Look at the bright side: Future readers of your code won't try to kill you.